# Cloud SQL Migrate from 1st to 2nd generation

Tags: database-migration, google-cloud-sql

We currently have a Cloud SQL instance with about 600 databases (10Gb total) and we have had several problems with crashes of the instance, so we are thinking about moving to a 2nd generation instance. However, I have found no tool in the console that does this.

Is there some way to do this other than exporting everything as SQL and then executing all queries in the new instance?

And as a side note, is there some limit to the amount of databases per instance? I have found no information on how many databases are recommended to avoid performance and reliability issues.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Export and import is the way to do it currently.

Google Cloud SQL uses practically unmodified MySQL binaries, so you can find the limits in the MySQL doc. This one is for 5.6: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/database-count-limit.html

The underlying OS, however, is a custom variant of Linux, and the limits is not documented at this point, but you are probably doing something wrong if you exceed the limits of the OS.